# Trying to connect two computers to a switch, but I get "cable unplugged" in the second one

Tags: linux, networking, router, fedora, switch

I have a modem-router, and I connected a switch to it. Then I connected a machine running Fedora 20 to the switch, and it said "cable unplugged". Restarting various services didn't help. Then I restarted the machine and it worked, I'm using that connection right now.

Then I connected a second machine with Fedora 17 to the switch, and it said cable unplugged, restarting various services didn't work. So I restarted the machine but that didn't work either!

I don't have access to the router, I think it's locked by the ISP company, but I think that shouldn't be necessary anyway. It should work just plugging in the cables like with the first machine, no?

What can I do?

Comment: Does the light come on when you plug it in?  Most likely you really are getting a link but the router is refusing to give you more than one IP address, and Fedora is just reporting a misleading error message.

Comment: Does your ISP-supplied modem-router provide DHCP, and for more than one device at a time?

Comment: Have you tried a different cable?

Comment: One of the new cables I bought was broken. Thanks @JSanchez!